# List of dictionaries with comprehension in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
    ld=[{'a':10,'b':20},{'p':10,'u':100}]
```

I want to write a comprehension like this:

```
    [ (k,v) for k,v in [ d.items() for d in ld ] ]
```

basically I want to iterate over dictionaries in the list and get the keys and values of each dict and do sth.

Example: One example output of this would be for example another list of dictionaries without some keys:

```
        ld=[{'a':10,'b':20},{'p':10,'u':100}]
        new_ld=[{'a':10},{'p':10}]
```

However, the above comprehension is not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: For example: create another list of dictionaries without some keys. For example:      ld=[{'a':10,'b':20},{'p':10,'u':100}] then  new_ld=[{'a':10},{'p':10,'u':100}]

Comment: Why are you keeping some keys and not others?

Comment: In "new_ld", some of the items are filter out from "ld". For example :  new_ld=[ (k,v) for k,v in [ d.items() for d in ld ] if k!='b' or k!='u']

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct list comprehension is `[[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in ld]`

Demo:

```
>>> ld = [{'a': 10, 'b': 20}, {'p': 10, 'u': 100}]
>>> [[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in ld]
[[('a', 10), ('b', 20)], [('p', 10), ('u', 100)]]
>>> [[(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k not in ['b','u']] for d in ld]
[[('a', 10)], [('p', 10)]]
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a list of tuples with the keys and values paired.

To do this you can do two for loops in a list comprehension, and use [.items()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm) to output the keys and values as tuples:

```
[kv for d in ld for kv in d.items()]
```

outputs:

```
[('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('p', 10), ('u', 100)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is problem  if I wan to do it this way, this comprehension would put all dictionaries as one long output.  For example: ld=[{'a':10,'b':20},{'p':10,'u':100}] then new_ld=[{'a':10},{'p':10,'u':100}], this com will not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the sequence:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ld = [{'a':10,'b':20},{'p':10,'u':100}]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in ld))
[('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('p', 10), ('u', 100)]
```

The other solution is to use double-`for` comprehension/generator but I find them very hard to read.