# How to concatenate list of dictionaries items using join and list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i'm trying to get a formatted string with all attributes from all dictionaries in a list using list comprehension

```
results = [{'TTL': '1643410114', 'customer': '1212', 'date': '2021-01-28', 'file': 'file.gz'}]

print("***** SEARCH RESULTS ***** \n".join([ f"{key}: {value}\n" for key, value in obj.items() for obj in results ]))
```

and I got `NameError: name 'obj' is not defined`, I tried some combinations without success, how can I archieve this?

Comment: This problem has already been addressed in:[List of dictionaries with comprehension in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924633/list-of-dictionaries-with-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of dictionaries with comprehension in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924633/list-of-dictionaries-with-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: what field is your key and what field is your value?  assume TTL is the key and filename is the value.  Do you see the ambiquity your approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your inline for-loops in the wrong order:

```
>>> [ "{}: {}\n".format(key, value) for obj in results for key, value in obj.items() ]
['customer: 1212\n', 'date: 2021-01-28\n', 'file: file.gz\n', 'TTL: 1643410114\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch the order of the two for loops.

```
results = [{'TTL': '1643410114', 'customer': '1212', 'date': '2021-01-28', 'file': 'file.gz'}]

print("***** SEARCH RESULTS ***** \n".join([ f"{key}: {value}\n" for obj in results for key, value in obj.items()]))
```

Output

```
TTL: 1643410114
***** SEARCH RESULTS ***** 
customer: 1212
***** SEARCH RESULTS ***** 
date: 2021-01-28
***** SEARCH RESULTS ***** 
file: file.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a path to do it...

```
print("***** SEARCH RESULTS *****")
print(str([k +' : '+ results[0][k] for k in results[0]]).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','\n').replace("'",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [{'TTL': '1643410114', 'customer': '1212', 'date': '2021-01-28', 'file': 'file.gz'},
      {'TTL': '1643410115', 'customer': '1312', 'date': '2021-02-27', 'file': 'file2.gz'}
      ]

#print(results)
for obj in results: 
     for key, value in obj.items():
        if (key=='file'):
             print(obj['TTL'],key,value)


output
1643410114 file file.gz
1643410115 file file2.gz
```